# explicit typing on methods of a numba jitclass

Tags: python, class, numba

Is there a way to explicitly type methods of a class that is compiled using numba's `jitclass` (v. 0.25)?

Example implementation of a LFSR:

```
@numba.jitclass([('charpoly',numba.uint64)])
class LFSR(object):
    def __init__(self,charpoly):
        self.charpoly = charpoly

#    @numba.njit('u8(u8,u8)')
    def advance(self,state,n):
        for k in range(n):
            state  = (state>>1) ^ (self.charpoly if (state&1) else 0)
        return state
```

Uncommenting the commented line will make numba complain about the missing type declaration for the `self` argument, but what should one put there?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to explicitly define the call signature of a instance method with jitclass. It still gets compiled, but will just use type inference. As long as you only pass in `(u8,u8)` arguments, it should be equivalent.

Comment: But when a type-problem appears deep down in the call stack during jit type-inference it becomes very hard to identify the origin of the problem...